# Avoid Overlap option not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, topology, overlapping-features

I am creating polygons in a FGDB layer inside QGIS. I have topology on with advance options and have checked avoid overlap option for that layer.
Still, I am getting overlap some times and some times not when I am creating new features. Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Overlap is a topological error when happening between parts of the same feature, but different features can overlap and thats not a topological error. I'm not totally sure, but if you can check that, I could search a source and write an answer..

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca in QGIS this feature not allow any geometry to overlap, from the same layer or another.

Comment: @Someone191 I used this daily at work and.. sometimes is work, sometimes is not, sometimes restarting qgis help.

Comment: @GSienko so it is a bug then?

Comment: In most of the cases is depends on how long qgis is open/or qeometry is in some way invalid. So I don't have confidence to tell that is a bug. I just using it as is.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. For me the issue was related to different CRS values for the corresponding layers - double check that they are all the same.