# Avoid overlap in QGIS sometimes works and sometimes doesn't for no apparent reason

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, quickmapservices

I have it set to "avoid overlap on active level" and "self-snapping" and "snapping on intersection" are both selected as well. I read this question: [Avoid Overlap option not working in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340172/avoid-overlap-option-not-working-in-qgis) but it didn't seem to arrive at an answer. I'm very, very new to this and basically all I know how to do is make polygons. As far as I can figure there is no difference between the ones that successfully avoid overlap and those that don't. It happens within the same shp file, the same work session. I draw one polygon and it doesn't overlap, draw another one right next to it and it does overlap.

I've also read this: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/2921 but I really don't understand what it's talking about.